# textblock as a curve in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I want to create a textblock that is curved. It it somewhat similar to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCJuQ.gif
[image: Textblock curved]
How can i do it in expression blend?
Even though i have tried setting a textblock on a path list box layout, it prints in vertical fashion rather than on the path layout.

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
            <TextBlock x:Key="TextRes" Text="world wide web"/>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
<mec:PathListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Text, Source={StaticResource TextRes}}">
            <mec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
                <mec:LayoutPath Orientation="OrientToPath">
                    <mec:LayoutPath.SourceElement>
                        <Ellipse Height="436" Width="352" />
                    </mec:LayoutPath.SourceElement>
                </mec:LayoutPath>
            </mec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
 </mec:PathListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with `PathListBox`. The key is to set `ItemsSource` to string and use `OrientToPath`. The following xaml is for WP7.

```
<mec:PathListBox xmlns:mec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Controls"
  ItemsSource="world wide web">
  <mec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
    <mec:LayoutPath Orientation="OrientToPath">
      <mec:LayoutPath.SourceElement>
        <Ellipse Height="91" Width="300"/>
      </mec:LayoutPath.SourceElement>
    </mec:LayoutPath>
  </mec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
</mec:PathListBox>
```

Even though the designer warns about the string, it compiles and runs. Or you could do:

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
  <TextBlock x:Key="TextRes" Text="world wide web"/>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
<mec:PathListBox
  ItemsSource="{Binding Text, Source={StaticResource TextRes}}">
  <mec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
    <mec:LayoutPath Orientation="OrientToPath">
      <mec:LayoutPath.SourceElement>
        <Ellipse Height="91" Width="300"/>
      </mec:LayoutPath.SourceElement>
    </mec:LayoutPath>
  </mec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
</mec:PathListBox>
```

Comment: It throws an error saying that itemssource cannot be set to string.

Comment: I am sorry to post your code in question. But this question was put on hold and i didnt get my answer yet. That displays text content in vertical fashion. Did you get expected thing for the code u gave me?